# Creating IAM policy and role in destination account

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Context:

At the moment I **manually** create a Policy and Role in the `stag` account (**destination**) to allow `devops` group users from the `root` account to list all S3 objects taht live in `stag` account. What I need to do is that, get rid of manual Policy and Role creation process in the `stag` account to have a configuration in Terraform which handles it as usual.

So far I tried replicating some examples that I've seen on the web but the problem is, most of them duplicate users in all accounts which is not fit for my setup. On the other hand, when I follow some other examples, the Policy and Role is created in the `root` account rather than the `stag` account. As a result using `role_arn = arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/devops` in CLI config for `john` gives me `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/john is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/devops`. I would greatly appreciate it if someone would help me out with this.

Setup:

- The `root` (`111111111111`) account is dedicated to IAM groups and users only, nothing else.

  - There is user `john` who is part of `devops` group.
- The `stag` (`222222222222`) account is dedicated to S3 only (for now), not for IAM groups or users.

  - There are many buckets.

Requirement:

- Allow `john` to run `$ aws s3 ls` to list all objects in all S3 buckets.

#### Manually created policy in stag account

```json
# arn:aws:iam::222222222222:policy/devops-role-permissions
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Manually created role in stag account

```json
# arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/devops
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Terraform root policy config

```json
resource "aws_iam_policy" "devops_role_assumption_in_stag_account" {
  name        = "devops-role-assumption-in-stag-account"
  description = "Allows devops group to assume role in stag account."

  policy = jsonencode(
    {
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement" : [
        {
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Action" : "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Resource" : "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:role/devops"
        }
      ]
    }
  )
}
```

#### Terraform root group policy attachment config

```json
resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "devops_role_assumption_in_stag_account" {
  group      = aws_iam_group.devops.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.devops_role_assumption_in_stag_account.arn
}
```

Comment: `john` is already in stag account. It does not make any sense for `john` to assume role in `root`, just to be able to list buckets in `stag` account. I think you have to re-think your entire accounts architecture and what users are supposed to be doing.

Comment: you can also use a bucket policy to grant access to s3 cross accounts - that is , without assuming a role

Comment: @Marcin - Maybe I worded something wrong but `john` lives in `root` account and wants to assume role in `stag` account to list objects in `stag` account.

Comment: So what does `john` do to assume the role? What commands is he using?